# Android layout interface rows of images

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm beginning android development, and I have a simple question about designing android interfaces. I'm trying to have row after rows of images, added dynamically, but I'm not sure how to do this so it wraps the edges of the screen. When I try to use a horizontal linearlayout, it goes off the edge of the screen. Is there a way to wrap the screen so it won't go off the edge? I wouldn't be able to use a relative layout, or a listview similar to that either, since screen sizes differ, and I wouldn't be able to hard-code the number of images into each row.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think all that you need is the GridView with the scroll bars if i have understood your question right... if so reffer this [link for gridview tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

hope this  could help...